# Use GIMP to import PDF as vector graphics rather than rasterized graphics

Tags: pdf, images, gimp, measurement

I need to use GIMP to measure the distance between sections of an image, but I noticed that GIMP seems to rasterize what I believe ought to be a vectorized PDF image.  Adobe Reader has no problem displaying a vectorized image, which seems to imply that the PDF file *is* vectorized, but when I open it with GIMP, it's rasterized.  I can't figure out how to make it display as a vectorized image.

Is it possible to make GIMP show the vectorized PDF, rather than a rasterized version?

Here's the vectorized Adobe Reader image:
[image]

And here's the rasterized GIMP rendition:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GIMP is a raster image editor, everything you open with it will turn into pixels, you should try inkscape or some other vector editor, if you still want to work with vectors you also need to enable anti-aliasing for text and graphics if you don't want blocky pixels.

Answer (score 2):

As it has been said, GIMP is a raster image editor.

Probably the cheapest tool giving you measuring features for PDF is Adobe Reader with the Measure tool.